# Oracle Forms Builder 11g Connect (Not Responding)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to connect Oracle Form Builder 11g to Oracle Database 11gR2. But when trying to connect then Connect(Not Responding).

My database is up and running and I am able to connect through SQL PLUS and SQL DEVELOPER.

I am using Oracle Froms Builder 11g from 3 Months without any issue. But I am getting this error since yesterday

[image]

Comment: What changed *since yesterday*?

Comment: My problem solved. Internet issue

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using the database you used while installing forms. It should be a plugable database (PDB)and not single container database(CDB). For my case it was ORCLPDB and not ORCL and I was able to connect.
Add the service in Listner.ora file